Need assistance with defining own Observable for validation of file upload in Angular 17
I'm following a tutorial for file upload in Angular 17, but in the tut, they use Observable.create, which is deprecated in Angular 17. I have read the docs on implementing the new system, but it does not work. Also, in the tut, they use a type Observer<{ [key: string]: any }>, but I cannot assign a type to null, which is this method called observer.next(null);
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

export const mimeType = (
  control: AbstractControl
): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> => {
  const file = control.value as File;
  const filereader = new FileReader();
  const fileObserver = new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
    filereader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
      const arr = new Uint8Array(filereader.result as ArrayBuffer).subarray(
        0,
        4
      );
      let header = '';
      let isValid = false;
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        header += arr[i].toString(16);
      }
      switch (header) {
        case '89504E4':
          isValid = true;
          break;
        case 'ffd8ffe0':
        case 'ffd8ffe1':
        case 'ffd8ffe2':
        case 'ffd8ffe3':
        case 'ffd8ffe8':
          isValid = true;
          break;
        default:
          isValid = false;
          break;
      }
      if (isValid) {
        observer.next(null);
      } else {
        observer.next({ invalidMimeType: true });
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
    filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
  return fileObserver;
};


Since the tutorial was not shared.
You can just set the type of Observer to Observer<{ [key: string]: any } | null>.
We also need to change the function return type to Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null>.
Basically, since we are also returning null, we use the typescript union operator | to indicate that it also allows null ({ [key: string]: any } | null)
export const mimeType = (
  control: AbstractControl
): Promise<{ [key: string]: any }> | Observable<{ [key: string]: any } | null> => {
  const file = control.value as File;
  const filereader = new FileReader();
  const fileObserver = new Observable((observer: Observer<{ [key: string]: any } | null>) => {
    filereader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
      const arr = new Uint8Array(filereader.result as ArrayBuffer).subarray(
        0,
        4
      );
      let header = '';
      let isValid = false;
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        header += arr[i].toString(16);
      }
      switch (header) {
        case '89504E4':
          isValid = true;
          break;
        case 'ffd8ffe0':
        case 'ffd8ffe1':
        case 'ffd8ffe2':
        case 'ffd8ffe3':
        case 'ffd8ffe8':
          isValid = true;
          break;
        default:
          isValid = false;
          break;
      }
      if (isValid) {
        observer.next(null);
      } else {
        observer.next({ invalidMimeType: true });
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
    filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
  return fileObserver;
};


Thank you very much for the explanation and I will work on it to learn more about angular
